# How compare vector size with an integer?

Tags: c++, vector

I am using the following code to throw an error if the size of vector (declared as `vector<int> vectorX`) is is different than intended.

```
vector<int> vectorX;
int intendedSize = 10;
// Some stuff here
if((int)(vectorX.size()) != (intendedSize)) {
    cout << "\n Error! mismatch between vectorX "<<vectorX.size()<<" and intendedSize "<<intendedSize;
    exit(1);
}
```

The `cout` statement shows the same size for both. **The comparison is not showing them to be equal**.

Output is `Error! mismatch between vectorX 10 and intendedSize 10`

Where is the error? Earlier I tried `(unsigned int)(intendedSize)` but that too showed them unequal.

Comment: Also, please show us your *actual* code.

Comment: @NPE Sorry, I tried to simplify actual code by typing it in question. In that process I made typo.

Comment: Write a short complete program that demonstrates the problem and then, before posting it, compile and execute it, to test that it actually has the same problem.  You'll find that the demo program _doesn't_ have the problem you thought it did and the problen is actually somewhere else than you thought.  So keep searching for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing `)` in the right side of if statement

```
if((int)(vectorX.size()) != (intendedSize)) {
                                          ^^^
}
```

But note, it's bad to cast return value of std::vector::size to int. You lose half of the possibilities of what the size could be(thanks to chris).

You should write:

```
size_t intendedSize = 10; 
// OR unsign int intendedSize  = 10; 
if(vectorX.size() != intendedSize) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You mean we can't go from size_t to int but we can go from int to size_t?

Comment: @user13107, You lose half of the possibilities of what the size could be.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected the typo. Even then the values are not being shown to be equal. What you said about casting, is it the reason behind this? Actually, I don't want to do `size_t intendedSize` because that variable is used as `int` at other places.

Comment: Because the size can only ever be positive, and `int` takes half the range and instead goes into the negatives. I should have said differently before as well, but it could be much more than half if `sizeof(size_t) > sizeof(int)`.

Comment: or use unsigned int, can you do that?

Comment: I tried `(unsigned int)(intendedSize)`. Same thing happens.

Comment: just remove your cast, see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks. It works. I wonder why my casting as `(unsigned int)` doesnt work though. Why cant it change int 10 to unsigned int 10? @user1131467

Comment: do you still have `(int)(vectorX.size())` in the front? otherwise cast from int to unsigned int should be fine.

Comment: yup thats it! what stupid mistake. thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 30):

I'm writing this answer because the other two, including the accepted one, are both wrong. The type of `std::vector`'s `size()` is not `unsigned int`, nor it is `size_t`.

The type of the size of an `std::vector<T>` is `std::vector<T>::size_type`.

That's it. On some architecture and for some compilers it might be the same as `size_t`, in some others it might not. The assumption that a variable of type `size_t` can hold the same values than one of type `std::vector<T>::size_type` can fail.

To check that your vector has the right size you could do something like:

```
if(vec.size() != static_cast<std::vector<int>::size_type>(expected_size)) {
    std::cerr << "Error!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: So you are actually saying that you should type for (std::vector<int>::size_type i=0; i<myVec.size(); ++i) {..} if you want to iterate over a vector using indexes? The only way to write this in a sane way that I see is using auto, what was the committee thinking? Why not just use int?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `size_t` type to hold collection sizes:

```
vector<int> vectorX;
size_t intendedSize = 10;
// Some stuff here
if(vectorX.size() != intendedSize) {
     ... 
}
```

Actually technically you should use `vector<int>::size_type` but in practice this is always a typedef for `size_t`

An `int` is usually a signed 32-bit integer.

`size_t` is usually an unsigned 64-bit integer (on 64-bit architectures) or an unsigned 32-bit integer (on 32-bit architectures).

(Note that the standard doesn't enforce those constraints.  The ABI specifies this, for example the x86 and x86-64 ABI do.)