# std::vector::size return an int type or unsigned int

Tags: c++, vector, c++14

In most of the programs I write using `std::vector`, most of my pains are converting

```
int offset=(int)v.size();
unsigned int offset=(unsigned int)v.size();
```

It is sad that such problems are reflected in many other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599057/how-compare-vector-size-with-an-integer).

Is there any way to rewire `std::vector` and force it to give size as an `int` or `unsigned int` like?

```
int offset=v.size_i();
```

Type-casts make the codes messier that what they are. Although, some programmers enjoy them and feel there is no problem with casting every time.

`c++14` solutions are more preferred but `c++17` solutions are also welcome.

If some one suggest to change the type of the variable, soon or late another type casting must happen. So it does not solve the problem.

Please consider such ugly phrases

```
function((int)myvar1.vec[32].size(),(int)myvar2.vec[32].size());
```

where `function` only accepts `int`s. And I have no control over its definition.

Comment: Use compiler type-deduction with `auto`? Like `auto offset = v.size()`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, If I need `offset` to be `int` as it is passed to another function, at the end another conversion should happen.

Comment: you could always create a `ssize()` that does that for you.

Comment: why don't you use implicit casts? Just cast to `signed`/`unsigned` when "comparing signed and unsigned" warning pops up

Comment: Will the "offset" always be a non-negative value? Then perhaps use `size_t` as the type. By the way, have you *tried* to build without the casting? I've tried it with plenty of extra warnings enabled, and doesn't get any compiler warnings about a plain assignment like `int offset = v.size();` Unless you have containers of more than 2 billion elements don't worry. And if you do then use `long long` instead.

Comment: `myvar1.vec[32].size()` already looks messy, could this be encapsulated into a function itself that gives you what you want?

Comment: If a function takes an int, you can usually just pass in unsigned or size_t and it will convert for you. No need to cast it manually.

Comment: @super, I always keep `-Wconversion` on.

Comment: @ar2015 I was talking about the whole method chain and not just the cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can inherit from `std::vector` and re-implement `size()` function to return signed value:

```
template<typename T, typename Alloc = std::allocator<T> >
class my_vector : public std::vector<T, Alloc>
{
    using base_t = std::vector<T,Alloc>;
public:
    using base_t::vector;
    using base_t::operator =;

    int size() const noexcept { return base_t::size(); }
};
```

Comment: Is `noexcept` vital?

Comment: Should be proposed for `c++20`.

Comment: @ar2015, if you ask me, I believe `std::vector::size` should return unsigned as size cannot be negative. `noexcept` isn't vital here, mostly provided for api consistency. But it may be of use in some possible scenarios

Comment: @ar2015 Remember that `std::vector` does not have a `virtual` destructor. It's not designed for (public) inheritance.

Comment: @ar2015 consider [submitting a proposal](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x, I should do it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude as soon a class is never used by pointer/reference to base instance, `virtual` destructor isn't required. And even if it was in this particular case, my implementation has no extra destructor routines.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<>.size()` is going to be `unsigned`. It is the way the class is wired, it even includes a `typedef` for what that type i.e. `std::vector<>::size_type`. It would be much better for you to get in the habit of using `unsigned` offsets.

Comment: Isn't it nicer if the type casting be performed by the library than the user everytime?

Comment: @ar2015 its better if the library is clear about return types, the size of a vector will never be negative, so an unsigned type is the better choice

Comment: I most of the applications you do not need your variables to be big. Also, the size is also used in many calculations where the final result can be negative and you need to type cast is to add/subtract it with the `int` variables. Assuming (`-Wconversion`) is on.

Comment: @ar2015 If it is just in *most* applications that you don't need them to be big, what about those where you do?

Answer (score 1):

In c++20 you can use [std::ssize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) which returns a signed int.

Use it as:

```
std::ssize(my_std_vector)
```

or:

```
my_std_vector.ssize()
```

The proposal introducing it to the standard library was [P1227R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1227r1.html).