# iteration through a very, very long std::vector question

Tags: c++, for-loop, stdvector

I have a `std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>>` which shall be able to accommodate potentially very many elements.

I do not know in advance how many elements it will have. It depends on how I run my code (with what input parameters).

I want to iterate over this vector.

At the moment, I am doing:

```
for (long long int idx = 0; idx <= (vec.size() - 1); idx++) {
    do_something(vec[idx]);
}
```

This produces the warning:
`warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'long long int' and 'std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> >::size_type' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]`

From SO, I understand that `vec.size()` returns a `std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> >::size_type`, which I understand that it potentially can not be the same as `size_t`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28514377/12248220

**My question is**:
How shall I write the for-loop to iterate through all the elements of the vector, without warnings?

For example, an `int` is not enough, I am sure the vector will hold more than `65535` elements.

Also, `long unsigned int`, what the compiler tells me that `.size()` returns, might be not enough to hold all the elements of my vector: from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types, it seems that it can go up to `4,294,967,295` only.

4 294 967 295 * 8 bytes = 34.3597384 gigabytes according to google, and yes, I do have more RAM than this (I am on a HPC server with 128 GB of ram per node).

This question can be also posed for a vector of ints only, there the multiplication above will be performed as  4 294 967 295 * 4 bytes ...

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you need an index and not just using iterators?

Comment: `idx` should be of type `std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>>::size_type` (currently it's a signed type, `size_t` is unsigned hence the warning). Bonus question: what happens when your `vector` has 0 elements?

Comment: `for (decltype(vec.size()) idx = 0; idx < vec.size(); ...` would be safe. Get used to half-open ranges.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees, I am using the ``idx`` variable inside the for-loop to index another buffer of memory as ``buffer[idx * N_rs + i]``, inside a for-loop over ``i`` (an int) and ``N_rs`` being a ``const int``

Comment: *"Also, long unsigned int, what the compiler tells me that .size() returns, might be not enough to hold all the elements of my vector"* `std::vector` has a `max_size()` member function. That is the maximum number of elements a `std::vector` of that type can contain. This should be at most the maximum value of the `difference_type` type which is a signed type and should be even less than the maximum value of `size_type`.

Comment: `using index_t = std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> >::size_type;` then `for (index_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I get your point. What is ``difference`` ? I have never seen it.

Comment: @velenos14 Typo, I meant `difference_type`. It is a type alias member of `std::vector` just like `size_type` except it is used to represent distance between two elements. It is basically a signed version of `size_type`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, thank you. Not even ``difference_type``, I have never seen it, so I didn't notice the typo :). I will read about these kind of stuff.

Comment: Thanks to all! Can someone post an answer me to accept it and close this question? For the current answer: I do not like ``auto`` because it seems to me that I do not understand what I am doing if I use it, even though I gather it is used in modern C++.

Comment: Hold on... maximum `size_type` for that is `4,294,967,295`? Are you compiling for a 32-bit target? Mine is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (i.e. 2^64 - 1).

Comment: @molbdnilo, no, it is a 64-bit architecture I am compiling on. I have read that value ``4,294,967,295`` from ``https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types``, from the ``Range of values`` paragraph. I based my idea on the fact that above it, I Read that for a ``unsigned long int``, at least 32 bits are used. Shall I have read that for a ``unsigned long int``, at least 64 bits are used?

Comment: @velenos14 `unsigned long long int` has at least 64 bits.

Comment: @velenos14 You should check what size it actually is on your specific architecture. (And you can look at the value of `std::vector<int>().size()-1`.)

Comment: @velenos14 - All the limitations work both ways - how you represent size and how large an object can be. As `size_t` is the return type of `sizeof`, nothing can be larger than what a `size_t` can hold. Your only "problem" would be that `szie_t` is *larger* than neeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand that `vec.size()` returns a `std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>>::size_type`

So use it:

```
for (decltype(vec.size()) i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    do_something(vec[i]);
}
```

You can also make am explicit type alias:

```
using IndexType = std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>>::size_type;
for (IndexType i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) { ... }
```

Or use a range-based for loop, optionally with an index on the side:

```
decltype(vec.size()) i = 0;
for (auto& value : vec) { // may be `auto const&` or even just `auto`
    do_something(value, i);
    ++i;
}
```

Or use iterators directly:

```
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
    // std::distance is constant-time with std::vector iterators (basically just `it - vec.begin()`)
    auto i = std::distance(vec.begin(), it);
    do_something(*it, i);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eozoq68YW)

Answer (score 10):

Prefer a ranged-based for:

```
for (const auto& elem : vec) {
    do_something(elem);
}
```

Under the hood it operates with pointers to vector elements. If an element can be pointed to, then it will be accessed by this loop. If an element cannot be pointed to, it cannot be stored in a vector anyway.

Comment: Correct, and good advice, but seems to side-step the question which the provided context implies is about what type to use to represent an element's position.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler issued the warning because in this for loop

```
for (long long int idx = 0; idx <= (vec.size() - 1); idx++) {
```

in the condition of the loop there are compared values of signed and unsigned integer types. At least you could write for example

```
for ( unsigned long long int idx = 0; idx < vec.size(); idx++) {
```

Though if you need to use indices to access elements of the vector then it would be better to write

```
for ( decltype( vec )::size_type idx = 0; idx < vec.size(); idx++ ) 
{
    do_something(vec[idx]);
}
```

otherwise you can use range-based for loop as for example

```
for ( const auto &elem : vec )
{
        do_something( elem );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the first thing you wrote solves my problem